# installing linux on dell poweredge T 110 (perc s300)

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, dell-perc

We have a PERC S300 machine on which we want to install Ubuntu server (or in the worst case any linux distribution). Many web sites say that it is not possible to install linux on perc s300. However, the manual which came along with the dell machine says that RedHat Enterprise linux would work on this hardware. But some redhat documents (obtained from web) claim that no linux distribution would work on perc s300. We do not have Redhat Enterprise with us to test it for ourselves. So my question is, is it possible to install linux on this hardware?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid PERC S300 only supports Windows operating system.

You may refer to the supported OS list:-
http://support.us.dell.com/support/edocs/storage/Storlink/PERC_S100_S300/en/HTML/a5_sectb.htm#wp1207764

MW@DeLL

Answer (score 1):

This is the [Redhat statement about the support of Perc S300 controllers](https://access.redhat.com/kb/docs/DOC-19840.pdf):

> The S100 and S300 PERC RAID controllers require special drivers and
>   software that can only run under certain Microsoft Windows Operating
>   Systems.  These drivers and software are not available for Linux and
>   therefore the devices will not operate in the Red Hat Enterprise Linux
>   environment.

As the S300 is a LSI1068E with customized firmware ([*"PERC S300 is a hybrid solution obtained by a firmware change for the LSI 1068E SAS controller. The conversion from LSI 
1068E SAS controller to PERC S300 is done using the firmware upgrade (using DRMK bootable USB in DOS method)"*](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/Dell_Software_RAID_Functionality_White_Paper.pdf)) it appears that there might be a way back to the original LSI firmware where board would turn into a simple non-RAID SAS controller [fully supported by the MPT driver for RHEL or any other Linux distro](http://www.lsi.com/downloads/Public/SCSI/SCSI%20Common%20Files/README_FOR_MPTLINUX_RHEL5_SLES10_PH14-4.00.43.00-1.zip.txt).

An easier option might be spending $100 for a new 1068E though.